# Is there a good reason for using User Defined Functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Over the time, SQL Server has reduced the gap between UDFs and Stored Procedures. Many a times,  you would be right using one or the other. The rule of thumb is Functions do a specific thing (getdate()), and Procedures usually do multiple things—many a times, complex business logic (sp_addarticle).

Our development team has created hundreds of functions, that are really causing performance issues. No matter how many rows a functions return, execution plan treat them as if they are returning one single row. This is causing the performance issues. Whenever there’s a bottle neck, we just convert the Functions into Procs! This approach is becoming a trend.

I know there are pros and cons for going one way or other. I have a couple of questions:

- Is there any negatives in converting all our Functions into Procs?
  (It’s going to be a Herculean task! But we might have to bite that
  bullet.)
- Is there anything that can be achieved ONLY in Functions? (I know
  there are things only UDFs do. For e.g. you can call a function in  a
  SELECT, or function can be referred in DEFAULTS. I’m not looking for
  such things.)
- What’s the maximum number of UDFs you have in your database? (Just
  curious.)

Comment: I'd be inclined to say you should relegate UDFs to jobs that you can do *only* by that means, even to the point of reorganizing queries to avoid reliance on UDFs where possible.  Also, some tasks belong in client programs instead of in the database in the first place, and you should certainly consider getting rid of UDFs that serve only such tasks, along with those tasks themselves.

Comment: I don't remember ever working with a DB that had more than a handful of UDFs.  On the other hand, I've worked with some that had boatloads of SPs.

Comment: Scalar and multi-statement UDFs are bad news stay away from them but Inline UDFs are your friends use them whenever you can :)

Comment: I have come to think of UDFs as a last-resort.  In almost every case when I have the option to use a UDF I'm able to find a better solution using a View or Stored Procedure.  I would start by finding the largest performance breakers and fix those before committing to a heruclean task.

Comment: The thing you can do with UDF that you can't (to the best of my knowledge) do with a stored proc is use them inline in a query.

Comment: @TabAlleman I would say that is a good thing as inline function calls are a performance timebomb. To be very clear, I mean using a scalar UDF as a column. You might be talking about using an inline table valued function in which case that would be a limitation of procs.

Comment: Oh I'm not saying it's good or bad.  I'm just answering his 2nd question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of this question really veers into heavily opinion based information, but here's what I'd say (trying to stay away from personal opinion):

1. The negative is that it's a herculean task ;)
2. No.  Stored procedures can do everything functions can do and more.  User Defined Functions can really be seen as a subset of stored procedures at this point.
3. I can't find what the absolute max is, but I try to avoid functions because they are very easy to get wrong and use improperly (in performance killing ways).

As an aside, have you tried using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` on your function definitions?  This can help performance if it's applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a complicated question with no precise answer (maybe you should post this on Quora) but i will try...

1. Besides the fact that you can't `SELECT * FROM MyStoredProcedure` I don't see any negative... On the other hand, you might get security, because SP must be invoked by `EXEC mySP` while USF not, so if a dev name a USF something like "LastYearOrders" another one might call it thinking it is a table... it also makes a cracker job a bit easier...
2. I dont think so...
3. I have none

Answer (score 1):

One reason is the ability to use a UDF in a calculated column. I guess another is the ability to use scalar valued functions.

Batch converting all of your UDFs sounds like a knee jerk reaction. Have you identified the root cause of the performance problems? Are there UDFs that are better suited as UDFs than sprocs?

Comment: Thank you JP. I agree with calculated column (computed column?), and inline functions. The root cause in our case is execution plan incorrectly thinks function returns a single row. When we convert the function code, to regular t-sql or a proc, we see a much better performance.